# Do I need to rebuild and deploy the build again after expiration of provisioning profile?

Tags: certificate, provisioning-profile

My Enterprise application is having more than 1000 users in production. Yesterday my provisioning profile got expired. From yesterday I got many calls of users that they did not able to use their app.

Is there any way so that the existing user don't need to install the new build again. Because its very difficult to tell more than 1000 users to reinstall the app again.

Please help me. The issue is with production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to get the new provisioning profile on the devices somehow.  The provisioning profile must get on the device, and you can simply provide the new profile by itself, or you can rebuild the app and the profile will be included in the app's payload.

There are a couple of ways to do this, but here are the most popular methods:

1. If the devices are managed using an MDM product, you can push the new profile out to the devices using the MDM capabilities. Again, you can use the MDM system to push just the provisioning profile, or you can push the new app build with the new provisioning profile.  Judging by the fact that you would be requesting users to re-download the app, I don't believe you are using MDM to manage the devices.
2. If you have older devices (iOS 7 and before), you can have the user manually install the new profile.  You can email the provisioning profile to the users, and they will be able to open the profiles on their device. Or you can host the profile on a web server and direct the users to open the link to install the profile. The app will then work with the new, valid profile.
3. Rebuild the app and re-distribute.  When the users download the app (or any other apps built with the profile if you are using a wildcard identifier on your profile), the new profile should replace the other one and the app will be able to launch.

Unfortunately, all of these methods require you to get the new profile downloaded from the developer site onto each of those devices.

Comment: Also, this is why it is important for enterprise apps in a non-MDM environment to build in some self-update capabilities.  You still would have needed to update the profile and rebuild the app weeks ago. Then you trigger the self update function to prompt the users to install the update at launch.

Comment: Thanks wottle but when I try to install provisioning profile with link then on iOS 9.0 and later it not get install. Is there any other way around to install it on iOS 9.0 and later.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that option 2 only works on devices running iOS 7 and before.  I will update my answer. Unfortunately, you are left with options 1 or 3.

Comment: Thanks Wottle but most of my production users are using iOS 9.0 and above

Comment: That is unfortunate.  I think your only option is to rebuild and have them all re-download.  I would seriously consider adding the self-update capability now or you will be in the same boat next year.

Comment: Thanks Wottle for help